# ZF1 : How to deal with percentages stored in database and data entered by the user?

Tags: php, zend-framework, filter

I'm trying to deal with the percentages in my application. The user enter a value like 12 (for 12%). I have to store this in my database as the ratio : 0.12.

Then I have to display it back as 12 (for 12%).

The part where I display it back is quite easy, I used a customized View Helper, which multiplies by 100 the element value.

The hard part is when the user enters the value. I first thought about a filter, which divide per 100 the value. It works to store the value in the database, but when I retrieve the value, the method "getValue()" applies the filter, so that I get the value 0.0012.

On a second thought, I tried to override the setValue() method, to also divide per 100 the value. But when I populate the form, the setValue is also called, which also gives me 0.0012.

I wonder how I can deal with this problem? Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Mayby use your divide filter not as form element filter but just before writing to your database in stand alone way. So it only work on updateing database. Therefore think about opposite filter whitch you will use after reading your database and populateing form. So user sees value 12 in form field.

Comment: Set a condition where the method should be called. i.e. if $insert is set, then call setValue(), if $update is set, but $insert is not - don't call it

Comment: I agree with Dmonix. If you're using something like doctrine as a database wrapper it would be really easy to implement this.

Comment: why all the gyrations? Whats wrong with storing the value as a simple integer?

Comment: The data entered by the user is used after in calculation, such as result = data1 * percentage. It is ugly to handle the data when it is used, it's better to store it like a ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem thanks to Dmonix comment. I created two methods in my model to handle the division just before the database insertion/update:

```
public function preInsert($event)
{
    $this->_updatePercentageValue();
}

public function preUpdate($event)
{
    $this->_updatePercentageValue();
}

private function _updatePercentageValue()
{
    $value = $this->getValue();
    if ($value != null) {
        $this->setValue($value / 100);
    }
}
```

I realized that handling it at the form level was not a good idea, because ZF1 doesn't give any hook to alter the data in this case.